# The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am running into an issue where **The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'** when it was already installed(I checked Nuget Package Manager)

**What I have tried:**

1: Directly copy dll to the Bin  folder because I notice it was missing. This did not work.

2: Uninstall and re-install it from Nuget Package Manager, after that, the same error still exist. On top of that, I got a new error

> The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
> System.Web.Optimization.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception
> with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified..

**Package Version: 1.1.3**

It is a **WebForm** Project, not MVC(there are many posts have solutions that's unique to MVC, so it is not applicable in my case)

I have installed both packages with the highest stable version, so I am not sure why Infrastructure is yelling at me.

Comment: It's a silly question, I know: have you added any #include System.Web.Optimization or similar?

Comment: @AmoRobb yeah I did.  using System.Web; and using System.Web.Optimization;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fortunately found the solution:

`Web.Optimization` requires `Web.Infrastructure`. When I reinstall `Web.Optimization`, it changed the `targetFramework` from 40 to 45, while `Infrastructure` is looking at 40. Also, despite the fact that I have infrastructure installed, the dll is also missing. I copied net40 version of dll for both `Web.Optimization` and `Web.Infrastructure` and then it worked.